# How to get the list of Apple active devices in current wifi network?

Tags: iphone, ipad, macos

I am going to a start a new Network based app. So please any one give me an idea on the below question.

How to get the list of Apple  active devices in current wifi network?

Comment: What is the big picture here ? What do you want to accomplish/solve ?

Answer (score 0):

There's no sensible way, as far as I can see. You can simulate `nmap` and try ping every IP your subnet, then try to fingerprint each IP that answers. But that's hardly a good solution (and very complicated).